# Creating task from item being sent based on text in subject

Tags: vba, outlook

I am automating the creation of tasks in Outlook.

I want this code to ask if I want to create a task after I click send Email. I want it to ask only if there is a specific header to the email. We are using "#CT-" as a signifier to create the task.

Original code can be found here:

https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/create-task-sending-message/

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim intRes As Integer
Dim strMsg As String
Dim objTask As TaskItem
Set objTask = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
Dim strRecip As String
Dim itm As MailItem

With itm
    .subject = "#CT-"
End With

If itm.subject Like "#CT-" Then
    strMsg = "Do you want to create a task for this message?"
    intRes = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Create Task")
End If

If intRes = vbNo Then
    Cancel = False
Else

    For Each Recipient In Item.Recipients
        strRecip = strRecip & vbCrLf & Recipient.Address
    Next Recipient

    With objTask
        .Body = Item.Body
        .subject = Item.subject
        .DueDate = Item.ReceivedTime + 28
        .ReminderSet = True
        .ReminderTime = Item.ReceivedTime + 7
        .Save
    End With

    Cancel = False

End If

Set objTask = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the error you see with the IF statement ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new `itm` - you want to work with the `Item` parameter, to see if its `subject` starts with your signifier. You can use the `Left` function on that `subject` to see if it matches your signifier.

**EDIT:** If you want to save the task in a folder other than the default 'To-Do List' Folder, you can `.Move` the task after saving it.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim strMsg As String
Dim objTask As TaskItem
Set objTask = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
Dim strSignifier As String
Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim inquiries As Folder

Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

On Error GoTo FolderError:
' Inquiries is a subfolder of Inbox
Set inquiries = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Inquiries")
On Error GoTo 0

strSignifier = "#CT-"
strMsg = "Do you want to create a task for this message?"

If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
    If Left(Item.Subject, Len(strSignifier)) = strSignifier Then
        If MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Create Task") = vbYes Then
            With objTask
                .Body = Item.Body
                .Subject = Item.Subject
                .DueDate = Item.ReceivedTime + 28
                .ReminderSet = True
                .ReminderTime = Item.ReceivedTime + 7
                .Save 'to default folder
                .Move inquiries
            End With
        End If
    End If
End If

Set objTask = Nothing
Exit Sub

FolderError:
    MsgBox "Unable to find the Inquiries folder - cannot save this email as a task."

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! The code worked great. Just one last addition I guess. My boss would like the task to be saved to a task list called "inquiries" rather than the default "To-Do List." Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Where is your "Inquiries" task list saved? I.e. is it on the same level as "To-Do List"? Probably the easiest way is to [.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/taskitem-move-method-outlook) your task once you've saved it.

Comment: Yes it is I believe. "Inquiries" is classified as a new task folder.

Comment: This looks like it should work. I just have a question in regards to the section defining the inquiries folder. Why does the code need to have the error check? Just so I better understand exactly what I'm doing

Comment: I added error checking to handle the various scenarios that could occur: if the `Inquiries` folder is in a different location, or named differently, or doesn't exist at all, you will not be able to `.Move` your task to it.